# Can you convert between enum types in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have some code in our project that looks like this:

```
static func getUrlFromPageType(_ type: PageType) -> UrlConfig? {
    switch type {
    case .helpScreen:
        return .helpScreen
    case .contact:
        return .contact
    case .termsAndConditions:
        return .termsAndConditions
    // etc
    }
}
```

It goes on like this for another 20 cases or so. With two exceptions (that map to nil), the "name" of the return value is always identical to the input, but the type is different.

Ideally you would probably want to use something a little more sensible than enums here, but for the purposes of this question, assume that won't be possible.

My question is: can I map from one enum to another automatically, avoiding the switch statement?

Comment: Swift's type system is mostly nominal. Even if two enums have identical structure, they're completely unrelated, so far as the type system is concerned. You can bridge between them using the same backing raw values as Joakim, but otherwise, these are just completely unrelated values that happen to have the same names. Macros might be able to help with this in the future. Though it begs the question: if theses have a strict 1-to-1 relationship, is there even a reason to have two distinct enums in the first place?

Comment: Why do you have two enums in the first place?

Comment: @Alexander I would also agree that this doesn't really make that much sense to do. It would be better to have some sort of lightweight instance that handles both cases, maybe; but unfortunately right now I'm kind of stuck with the enums for reasons.

Answer (score 4):

If both the enums has a raw value of type String or you can change them to have that then it is quite simple

```
enum PageType: String {
    case helpScreen
    case contact
    case termsAndConditions
}

enum UrlConfig: String {
    case helpScreen
    case contact
    case termsAndConditions
}

func getUrlFromPageType(_ type: PageType) -> UrlConfig? {
    UrlConfig(rawValue: type.rawValue)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: can I map from one enum to another automatically, avoiding the switch statement?

No. We do a *lot* of this in our app, for enums that have a *lot* of cases, and there is no way around it: you just have to have a massive switch that maps each case of the first enum onto the corresponding case of the second enum — even though it is perfectly obvious how to do the mapping because the cases have the same names throughout.

Our convention is to give each enum that needs to be transformed into another a method that performs the transformation. So for example:

```
    enum ConfettiAnimation: String {
        case airborne = "Airborne"
        case anniesBunny = "AnniesBunny"
        // ... 20 more cases

        func toEarningsAnimation() -> EarningsAnimation? {
            switch self {
            case .airborne:
                return .airborne
            case .anniesBunny:
                return .anniesBunny
            // ... 20 more cases
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically you just have to do it the same way Superman puts on his pants — one leg at a time just like everyone else.

Comment: A caveat: If the enums both have a raw type of String you could map from one to the other using their rawValues as in Joakim's answer. (or if they have matching Int or other raw values, for that matter.)

Comment: True! But for other reasons, they don't.